# How do i get the Timestamp to update, when the cell contains a formula referencing another cell in another worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba, timestamp, range, automatic-updates

The following code is what gives me an initial timestamp (`N`) and updated time (`O`).

This works when the cell's in column `D` on `WORKSHEET1` are manually updated.

The cell's in Column `D` `WORKSHEET1` reference `WORKSHEET2` Column `E` now. So for example `D4` on `WORKSHEET1` is `='WORKSHEET2'!E23`.

When values are updated on `WORKSHEET2`, the `D` column on `WORKSHEET1` updates automatically.

The timestamp code below then stops working and does not pick up this value change.
Can I insert a VBA code so that when i change the values on `WORKSHEET2`, and it updates on `WORKSHEET1` because of the formula in cel `D`, the timestamp will work?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim myTableRange As Range

Dim myDateTimeRage As Range

Dim myUpdatedRange As Range

Set myTableRange = Range("D1:D314")

If Intersect(Target, myTableRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Set myDateTimeRage = Range("N" & Target.Row)

Set myUpdatedRange = Range("O" & Target.Row)

If myDateTimeRage.Value = "" Then

    myDateTimeRage.Value = Now
End If

myUpdatedRange.Value = Now

End Sub
```

Comment: This code runs when a change is detected in the worksheet the code is saved to.  Also, without qualify a sheet, `Range()` will refer to the active sheet (which I assume is the same one that stores this code).

Comment: Put the code in Worksheet2 code and then change the cells on worksheet1.

Comment: So should i use with after i set my range? to reference the range on the non-active sheet? not sure what function to use

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim myTableRange As Range
    Dim myDateTimeRage As Range
    Dim myUpdatedRange As Range
    Set myTableRange = Range("D1:D314")   

    For Each cell In myTableRange
        Dim OldValue As Variant
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.Undo
        OldValue = cell.Value
        Application.Undo
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        If OldValue <> cell.Value Then
            Set myDateTimeRage = Range("N" & cell.Row)
            Set myUpdatedRange = Range("O" & cell.Row)    
                If myDateTimeRage.Value = "" Then
                    myDateTimeRage.Value = Now
                End If
            myUpdatedRange.Value = Now
        End If    
    Next cell
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, This code has a compile error."Expected end sub" and it highlights the first line of code yellow.

Comment: @leslie just add `End Sub` after the last line of code and it will work.